# Cycle through, Show and Hide Text/div on first/last click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I'm making something for a site and can't figure this one out.

How can I make this `div` appear on the first button click, cycle through the array, then disappear after the last item in the array?

```js
var myArray = ["Hello", "Thank you", "Goodbye"];
var myIndex = 1;
var print = document.getElementById('print');

print.innerHTML = myArray[0]; //Print first value of array right away.

function nextElement() {
  print.innerHTML = myArray[myIndex++ % myArray.length];
};
```

```css
#notfound {
  background: #2abfffff;
  padding: 19px;
  margin: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="notfound">
  <p><span id="print"></span>.</p>
</div>

<a id="click" href="#" onclick="nextElement();">Click</a>
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jBJ3B/382/

Comment: Do you want each of these events to be triggered by click to trigger each step, or do you want the entire sequence you've described to happen on one click?

Comment: @ggorlen I want the "not found" div to not display until the button is clicked, and for it to cycle through the 3 listed items on the array, and on the final click, the notfound div disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't want the div to appear before the first click, remove the line with `//Print first value of array right away.`.

One option is to start with an index of -1, make the element visible when the index is 0, and hide the element when the index is higher or equal to the length of the array:

```js
var arr = ["Hello", "Thank you", "Goodbye"];
var index = -1;
var print = document.getElementById('print');

function nextElement() {
  index++;
  if (index >= arr.length) {
    print.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    return;
  }
  if (index === 0) print.style.visibility = 'visible';
  print.textContent = arr[index];
}
```

```css
#notfound {
  background: #2abfffff;
  padding: 19px;
  margin: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
.print {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="notfound">
  <p><span id="print"></span>.</p>
</div>

<a id="click" href="#" onclick="nextElement();">Click</a>
```

If you need the element to re-appear on further clicks, then use modulo to set `index` to `-1` at the end:

```js
var arr = ["Hello", "Thank you", "Goodbye"];
var index = -1;
var print = document.getElementById('print');

function nextElement() {
  index++;
  if (index >= arr.length) {
    print.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    index = -1;
    return;
  }
  if (index === 0) print.style.visibility = 'visible';
  print.textContent = arr[index];
}
```

```css
#notfound {
  background: #2abfffff;
  padding: 19px;
  margin: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
.print {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="notfound">
  <p><span id="print"></span>.</p>
</div>

<a id="click" href="#" onclick="nextElement();">Click</a>
```

Comment: How can I make the entire #notfound div also appear and disappear along with the text?

Comment: Just select it instead of `#print`, and assign to its visibility instead of to `print`s

Answer (score 0):

You can check inside nextElement() if that element was the last one, and then just hide the div.

```
   function nextElement() {
      print.innerHTML = myArray[myIndex++%myArray.length];
      if(myIndex>myArray.length){
        document.getElementById("notfound").style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
   };
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jBJ3B/384/

Comment: How can I make it so it does exactly this, but the div does not display on load and only appears with "Welcome" after the first click?

Comment: @lps666 you can simply add an else to that code setting the visibility to "visible" when myIndex is ==0. Note that this to work the myIndex should be initialized with -1.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you trying to do:http://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/jBJ3B/393/.

If yes only add that line:

```
document.getElementById('notfound').style.display = 'none';
```